# Can not crawl the review with json() type

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I am crawling the rating and review from the website : "https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Topdekmatras-80x200-koudschuim-comfort-plus-tijk-5-cm-hoog/9200000116759797/"

I have 2 links containing json() type :
https://www.bol.com/nl/ajax/dataLayerEndpoint.html?product_id=9200000116759797  ==> to get the rating
https://www.bol.com/nl/rnwy/productPage/reviews?productId=9200000116759797&offset=0&limit=30&loadMore=true ==> to get the number of review.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product_link = "https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Topdekmatras-80x200-koudschuim-comfort-plus-tijk-5-cm-hoog/9200000116759797/"
rating_link = "https://www.bol.com/nl/ajax/dataLayerEndpoint.html?product_id=" + str(product_link[-17:].replace("/",""))
review_link = "https://www.bol.com/nl/rnwy/productPage/reviews?productId=%s&offset=0&limit=30&loadMore=true" %(str(product_link[-17:].replace("/","")))
review_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(product_link).text, "lxml")
reviewtitle= [i.get_text() for i in review_soup.find_all("strong", class_="review__title")]
product_attributes = requests.get(rating_link).json()
```

However, it threw the error for the last line of code:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Why I cant not get the JSON data?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error from the given code.

Comment: just ask my friend, she can run the code also, I don't know why it happened with me.

Comment: i just make a simple get request and i'm able to read the json data with no problem !

Comment: whats your BeautifulSoup version? `bs4.__version__`

Comment: it is :  '4.9.3'

Comment: I can crawl it again after waiting for a while. However, the number of links I can crawl always are 73 links. Idk why.

Comment: maybe it's serverside problem, also have you tried on another hardware/os configuration?